# how to programmatically dump data(bulk write) to elastic search

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I am trying to learn the ropes of elastic search. As part of QA testing, I want to write massive number of records  to ES(say 10K records). Each record is a geo location (x,y) coordinate. Each write will arbitrarily increase the value of (x,y).  I can have a counter that I can update in every loop operation in Java and write to ES. But I am guessing there may be a better way (because in ES documentation, I come across _bulk keyword). 
Is there any ES way of doing massive programmatic writes to ES

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the bulk API in Elasticsearch to add multiple documents at once. The API and examples are described in Elasticsearch: The Definitive guide which can be found here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/bulk.html

I'm guessing you would want to build a string like this:

```
{ "index": { "_index": "locationstorage", "_type": "geolocation" }} \n 
{ "xcoord":    1, "ycoord": 2 } \n 
{ "index": { "_index": "locationstorage", "_type": "geolocation" }} \n 
{ "xcoord":    2, "ycoord": 3 } \n
```

and POST it to the /_bulk API